# CentOS 8 with vhost suexec , PHP and HTTP2

Tags: apache, http2, vhosts, suexec, centos8

I am testing new CentOS 8 for hosting PHP web apps. 
For years I used to use some suexec solution to run PHP code under linux user account (different user for each virtual host). This way the application could write to its own files but not to a different app space. 
In CentOS 7 I used to use mod_ruid2 but for CentOS 8 it is not avaiable because lack of compatibility with HTTP/2 (this is what I found on the Internet so far).
I use PHP 7.3 from REMI repository.
I am also playing with php-73-fpm as I found some info that suexec might be there but coldn't find any good documentation for this...

QUESTION:
Does anyone found a way to have suexec on a Virtual Host level running CentOS8 with its default apache 2.4.37-12?
Would be good to stay with PHP from REMI.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, on RHEL or CentOS 8, FPM is used to serve PHP scripts.

You can create 1 pool per user (in /etc/php-fpm.d), and configure each vhost to use the proper pool (SetHandler)

Some explanation, examples in [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/)